# Image enlarge on click and hotspots

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large map of the UK with multiple walking routes marked on. Currently the map is split into zones but walkers have asked to see the map as a whole so they can link routes together.

However, the routes then look very small. Is it possible to have a map with a clickable scale on one side that allows then to zoom into an area of the map. The map needs to be draggable and once zoomed in to still allow hotspotting. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What have you done so far?

Comment: This post describes what I have done so far and also links to demos. Thanks. http://gucu.org.uk/computing/combining-resizing-an-image-and-image-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the map with a ***init()*** function and pass necessary parameters that would enable controls like zoom and drag.

Add this code to your Google Map page.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
      mapTypeIds: [
        google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

For additional details, take a look at this official [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-options).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I wasn't using Google Maps at the moment. Just a large map of the UK on our site.

Comment: @RichardBrown So why was the question tagged with Google Maps?

Comment: Hi I didn't tag it. It was after I posted the question. I only used the javascript and jquery tags.